# Verb takes last position in Hauptsatz. Is this possible?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, question

I took out the following sentence from a text:

> Was ich am meisten an Maria mag? Ihre Augen.

I would like someone to explain me what is going on here. I can see the verb takes the last position in the sentence. However, I cannot see any word that introduces a Nebensatz, which would justify this verb’s position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word that introduces a subordinate clause is the *was*. The sentence is missing an implicit *Das*:

> Das, was ich am meisten an Maria mag?

or:

> Das, was ich am meisten an Maria mag, sind ihre Augen.

Other, equally valid refillings would be:

> Willst du wissen, *was ich am meisten an Maria mag?*

---

Note that it is also possible to say:

> Was mag ich am meisten an Maria?

however, in this case you're not immediately suggesting to have an answer, you're just asking the question.

Comment: so "was" here introduces a relative clause. Is that correct?

Comment: @VassilisDe: Yes